# Can classes used in .ser java file be edited after .ser file creation?

Tags: java, file-handling, serializable

I am trying to load a .ser file of a class I made a while back.

But I'm getting `ClassNotFoundException`.

I'm wondering, is it because I made changes to the class used in those files?
Because the class name is the same, the only changes are some new methods.

If this is the case, is there a way I load .ser files that had their classes changed after creation?

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ebay.ItemEditObject
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at ebay.EbayMaster.getObjFromFile(EbayMaster.java:750)
at ebay.EbayMaster.createItemsForUpload(EbayMaster.java:340)
at ebay.EbayMaster.ebayRunner(EbayMaster.java:129)
at ebay.EbayMaster.main(EbayMaster.java:92)
```

Comment: You say you have a `ClassNotFoundException` but your traceback shows a `FileNotFoundException`? Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering, is it because I made changes to the class used in those files?

No.

> Because the class name is the same, the only changes are some new methods.

That could cause an `InvalidClassException`. Not a `ClassNotFoundException`.

But you aren't getting either of these. You're getting `FileNotFoundException.` The file wasn't found. Look again.

Comment: I just see it, i changed it from ItemEditObject to ItemEditObj. silly me